# Set the title of context menu for Windows 10 Task Bar icon

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, mfcc

I have an open source application I wrote for my own use that is a text and clipboard reader for Microsoft Windows. The application, which I unimaginatively named TTSApp, can be found on [my web site](https://svn.sullivanandkey.com/SnKOpen/cpp/TTSApp/trunk/).

The application uses MFC and can be built with either Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015, although window resizing only works properly when it is built with Visual Studio 2013. It uses MFC and, as a result, cannot easily be ported to other platforms or compilers.

It currently uses either SAPI 5 or the Microsoft Speech Platform for speech.

I have a GetTitle function that constructs the title of the application to indicate what configuration is in use, SAPI or Microsoft Speech Platform, and what architecture is in use, x86 or x64. For example, the title of the Microsoft Speech Platform configuration built for the x64 platform is "SnKOpen TTSApp - Microsoft Speech Platform - x64." This tile is used for both the window title of the dialog box and App Name (the value returned by the function is passed to the constructor of the CWinApp class). Note that the App Name is used to generate the windows registry key that application settings are stored in.

I have not been able to figure out how to set the title of the Windows 10 Task Bar icon context menu. The following screen shot will illustrate what I mean.

[image: TTSApp Windows 10 Taskbar Icon Context Menu]

I would like to set the TTSApp in the above image to be the same as the dialog box title bar.

I tried calling [CWinApp::SetAppID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee247525.aspx), which in turn calls the [SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378422(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 API function, from the constructor of the CTTSAppApp class, but that did not do it.

The description of the SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID implies that this is the way to accomplish what I want since the function "Specifies a unique application-defined Application User Model ID (AppUserModelID) that identifies the current process to the taskbar."

Does anyone have any suggestions about what I should attempt next?

Comment: Editing out all of the irrelevant narrative from your question to make it more clear what you're asking? The first two paragraphs and about half of the third have absolutely no meaning in regards to your question, and removing them (about 60% of your post) would greatly improve it's clarity.

Comment: The name in the jump list is the name of the group, which comes from the version resource of the executable.

Comment: Which means it can't be customized dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Note that you have to change app executable name to propogate the change, because otherwise it will not show up as it is cached somewhere in Windows.

Comment: Windows will eventually figure it out, but it does take a long time.